# Swift on iOS 17 - Popover with modalPresentationStyle is not transparent

Tags: ios, swift, ios17

I have a problem with Popover on iOS17.
On iOS15 and iOS16, my code works fine.

**Problem**

Even if the backgroundColor of the view of the ViewController's view to be displayed in Popover is set to clear, it is not transparent in iOS17.

[image: on iOS17.0]

[image: on iOS16.4]

**My Code**

Here is my code.

```
class MessageRoomView: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, MessagePopMenuViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    private func presentPopover(indexPath: IndexPath, sourceRect: CGRect, type: CustomMessageType, isLoginUser: Bool) {
        guard let currentCell = messageCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {
            initPopoverItem()
            return
        }
        self.popoverItem.indexPath = indexPath
        // current cell position from indexPath
        var cellPosition: CGRect {
            let point = CGPoint(x: currentCell.frame.origin.x - messageCollectionView.contentOffset.x, y: currentCell.frame.origin.y - messageCollectionView.contentOffset.y)
            let size = currentCell.bounds.size
            return CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        }
        // Determination of whether the user is present in the location/range
        guard let navBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height else {
            initPopoverItem()
            return
        }
        let isOutOfRange = cellPosition.height > (messageCollectionView.frame.height - navBarHeight - 300)
        
        /* 1. Check if Message size is within range */
        if !isOutOfRange {
            // Determines whether it is upward or downward
            let isUpper = cellPosition.minY <= messageCollectionView.frame.minY + 210
            
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: MessagePopMenuViewController.storyboardName, bundle: nil)
            let popMenuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: MessagePopMenuViewController.storybaordId) { coder in
                return MessagePopMenuViewController(coder: coder, isLoginUser: isLoginUser, isUpper: isUpper, type: type)
            }
            popMenuVC.delegate = self
            popMenuVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = currentCell
            popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceRect
            popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = sourceRect.width > 50 ? (isUpper ? .up : .down) : .unknown
            popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = MessagePopoverBackgroundView.self
            popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
            
            present(popMenuVC, animated: true)
            
        } else {
            
            let minYThreshold = messageCollectionView.frame.minY + 60
            let maxYThreshold = messageCollectionView.frame.maxY - 180
            let minYInThreshold = cellPosition.minY >= minYThreshold && cellPosition.minY <= maxYThreshold
            let maxYInThreshold = cellPosition.maxY >= minYThreshold && cellPosition.maxY <= maxYThreshold
            let isWithinThreshold = minYInThreshold || maxYInThreshold
            
            /* 2.a. Judges whether the PopMenu exists within the range that can be displayed on either the top or bottom of the screen. */
            if isWithinThreshold {
                // Determines whether it is upward or downward
                let isUpper = maxYInThreshold
                
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: MessagePopMenuViewController.storyboardName, bundle: nil)
                let popMenuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: MessagePopMenuViewController.storybaordId) { coder in
                    return MessagePopMenuViewController(coder: coder, isLoginUser: isLoginUser, isUpper: isUpper, type: type)
                }
                popMenuVC.delegate = self
                popMenuVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = currentCell
                popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceRect
                popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = isUpper ? .up : .down
                popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = MessagePopoverBackgroundView.self
                popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
                
                present(popMenuVC, animated: true)
                
            } else {
                /* 2.b. Popover on either the top or bottom if it does not exist within the displayable area, or in the center if it does not exist within the displayable area */
                if cellPosition.midY > 0 && cellPosition.midY < messageCollectionView.frame.maxY {
                    
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: MessagePopMenuViewController.storyboardName, bundle: nil)
                    let popMenuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: MessagePopMenuViewController.storybaordId) { coder in
                        return MessagePopMenuViewController(coder: coder, isLoginUser: isLoginUser, isUpper: false, type: type)
                    }
                    let rect = CGRect(x: sourceRect.minX, y: sourceRect.maxY - sourceRect.height / 2, width: sourceRect.width, height: sourceRect.height / 2)
                    popMenuVC.delegate = self
                    popMenuVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                    popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = currentCell
                    popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = rect
                    popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
                    popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = MessagePopoverBackgroundView.self
                    popMenuVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
                    
                    present(popMenuVC, animated: true)
                } else {
                    /* 2.c. out of range */
                    initPopoverItem()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }






import UIKit

final class MessagePopoverBackgroundView: UIPopoverBackgroundView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        setupPathLayer()
    }
    
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()
        let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        if let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene, let window = windowScene.windows.first {
            let transitionViews = window.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITransitionView" }
            for transitionView in transitionViews {
                let shadowView = transitionView.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UICutoutShadowView" }.first
                shadowView?.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - UIPopoverBackgroundViewMethods
    
    override static func arrowBase() -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
    
    override static func arrowHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
    
    override static func contentViewInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .zero
    }
    
    // MARK: - UIPopoverBackgroundView properties
    
    private var _arrowOffset: CGFloat = 0
    override var arrowOffset: CGFloat {
        get { return _arrowOffset }
        set { _arrowOffset = newValue }
    }
    
    private var _arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection = .unknown
    override var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection {
        get { return _arrowDirection }
        set { _arrowDirection = newValue }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Drawing
    
    /// UIBezierPathで吹き出しを描画する
    private func setupPathLayer() {
        layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        
        let rect = bounds
        let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pathLayer.frame = rect
        pathLayer.path = generatePath(rect).cgPath
        pathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        pathLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
    }
    
    private func generatePath(_ rect: CGRect) -> UIBezierPath {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = {
            var insets = MessagePopoverBackgroundView.contentViewInsets()
            if _arrowDirection == .up {
                insets.top += MessagePopoverBackgroundView.arrowHeight()
            } else if _arrowDirection == .down {
                insets.bottom += MessagePopoverBackgroundView.arrowHeight()
            }
            return insets
        }()
        
        let arrowBase = MessagePopoverBackgroundView.arrowBase()
        let arrowCenterX = rect.size.width / 2 + _arrowOffset
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        if _arrowDirection == .up {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX - arrowBase / 2, y: insets.top))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX + arrowBase / 2, y: insets.top))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX - arrowBase / 2, y: insets.top))
        } else if _arrowDirection == .down {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX - arrowBase / 2, y: rect.maxY - insets.bottom))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX + arrowBase / 2, y: rect.maxY - insets.bottom))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowCenterX - arrowBase / 2, y: rect.maxY - insets.bottom))
        }
        path.close()
        
        return path
    }
}
```

[image]

```
import UIKit

final class MessagePopMenuViewController: UIViewController {
    
    static let storyboardName = "MessagePopMenuViewController"
    static let storybaordId = "MessagePopMenuViewController"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var replyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var copyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stickerButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var showImageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var unsendButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuSpaceView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topReactionStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomReactionStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var reactionButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    private let isLoginUser: Bool
    private let isUpper: Bool
    private let type: CustomMessageType
    
    weak var delegate: MessagePopMenuViewControllerDelegate?
    private let reactionArray = ["❤️", "", "", "", ""]
    
    init?(coder: NSCoder, isLoginUser: Bool, isUpper: Bool, type: CustomMessageType) {
        self.isLoginUser = isLoginUser
        self.isUpper = isUpper
        self.type = type
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    deinit {
        // print("MessagePopMenuViewController deinit")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        reactionButtons.forEach({ $0.backgroundColor = .clear })
        topReactionStackView.backgroundColor = .clear
        bottomReactionStackView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        switch (isLoginUser, isUpper) {
        case (true, true) :
            topReactionStackView.isHidden = true
            menuSpaceView.isHidden = true
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 261, height: 130)
            replyButton.clipsToBounds = true
            replyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            replyButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
            unsendButton.clipsToBounds = true
            unsendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            unsendButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            
        case (true, false):
            bottomReactionStackView.isHidden = true
            menuSpaceView.isHidden = true
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 261, height: 130)
            replyButton.clipsToBounds = true
            replyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            replyButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
            unsendButton.clipsToBounds = true
            unsendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            unsendButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            
        case (false, true):
            topReactionStackView.isHidden = true
            unsendButton.isHidden = true
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 251, height: 130)
            replyButton.clipsToBounds = true
            replyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            replyButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
            menuSpaceView.clipsToBounds = true
            menuSpaceView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            menuSpaceView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            
        case (false, false):
            bottomReactionStackView.isHidden = true
            unsendButton.isHidden = true
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 251, height: 130)
            replyButton.clipsToBounds = true
            replyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            replyButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
            menuSpaceView.clipsToBounds = true
            menuSpaceView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            menuSpaceView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        }
        
        switch type {
        case .text, .reply:
            stickerButton.isHidden = true
            showImageButton.isHidden = true
        case .image:
            copyButton.isHidden = true
            stickerButton.isHidden = true
        case .sticker:
            copyButton.isHidden = true
            showImageButton.isHidden = true
        case.talk:
            self.dismiss(animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    // some IBAction later
}
```

Xcode - Version 15.0 (15A240d)
iOS - 17.0
macOS - macOS Sonoma version14.0